# Prevent multiple clicks .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do my own slider with jquery. Everything is ok but when the user click multiple times on the arrow to get the next picture it start to do strange things:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#arrow-right").click(function(){
        nextPrevius(1);
    });
    $("#arrow-left").click(function(){
        nextPrevius(-1);
    });
});

function nextPrevius(value){
    var id = parseInt($(".activo").attr("id"));
    if(id+value<1){
        $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#5").fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $(".activo").removeClass("activo");        
        $("#5").addClass("activo");
    }
    else if(id+value>5){
        $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#1").fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
        $("#1").addClass("activo");
    }
    else{
        $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#"+(id+value)).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
        $("#"+(id+value)).addClass("activo");
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.activo{
    display: block;
}
.contenido-slider{
    background-color: #d0d2ff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;

}
.contenido-slider span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
}
#arrow-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
    <body>

        <section id="slider">
            <div id="1" class="activo contenido-slider">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
            <div id="arrow-left">Prev</div>
            <div id="arrow-right">next</div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know i can use:

```
$(this).removeAttr('disabled');
```

But this is not a button and when i use a button and i set disabled attribute the cursor change to a forbidden signal and i don't want that.

How can i prevent to multipleclicks?

And yes i've reading a lot of info on internet and also in this forum but i can't prevent multiple clicks.

Comment: You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln637521/

Comment: probably issue with your animations. Might need to call `stop()`

Comment: You can change the "forbidden" cursor to any other cursor by adding a css for disabled button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next modifications i have made to the Javascript code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $("#arrow-right").click(function() {
        nextPrevius(1);
    });

    $("#arrow-left").click(function() {
        nextPrevius(-1);
    });
});

function nextPrevius(value)
{
    // Just for safe, check if there is an active slider.

    if ($(".activo").length <= 0) return;

    // Get the ID of the current active slider.

    var id = parseInt($(".activo").attr("id"));

    // Get the number of total sliders.

    var totalSliders = $(".contenido-slider").length;

    // Get the ID of the next element we need to fade-in.

    var nextId = id + value;

    if (nextId < 1)
        nextId = totalSliders;
    else if (nextId > totalSliders)
        nextId = 1;

    // Hide the current active slider and fade-in the needed one.

    $(".contenido-slider.activo").removeClass("activo").fadeOut("slow", function()
    {
        $("#" + nextId).fadeIn("slow").addClass("activo");
    });
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.activo{
    display: block;
}
.contenido-slider{
    background-color: #d0d2ff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;

}
.contenido-slider span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
}
#arrow-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
        <title>Slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="slider">
            <div id="1" class="activo contenido-slider">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
            <div id="arrow-left">Prev</div>
            <div id="arrow-right">next</div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would get the answer why yours is running perfectly as i wanted to

Comment: Thanks, just made a minor change to check if there is an active element on the **nextPrevious()** method.

Comment: I have made another minor improvement, so there is no element with the active class while the fade-in/fade-out is in progress.

Comment: @D.Smania you can adapt it and make it for inline use, check my answer, and then you can determine direction based on nav-buttons `id`'s

Comment: @darklightcode i will give it a review later. I also like the idea of non-depending of the hardcoded number of elements and get it like `$(".contenido-slider").length`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made you a navigation function with the following improvments:

- strict navigation only with "left" & "right"
- prevent spamming on navigation buttons
- you can add unlimited slides with `.contenido-slider`
- you can adjust the slide fade-in-fade-out speed

In **HTML** i removed `display:none` from `.contenido-slider`

In **CSS** i changed this part:

```
.contenido-slider {
  background-color: #d0d2ff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: none;
}

.contenido-slider.activo {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow-right").click(navigation('right'));
  $("#arrow-left").click(navigation('left'));
});

function navigation(direction) {

  return function(e) {

    /**
     * Accept only "left" or "right"
     */

    if (typeof direction === 'undefined' || ['left', 'right'].indexOf(direction) === -1) {
      direction = 'left'; // previous
    }

    var slider = $("#slider");
    var preventSpamClass = 'animation-in-progress';

    if (!slider.hasClass(preventSpamClass)) {

      slider.addClass(preventSpamClass)

      var activeClass = 'activo';
      var elements = slider.children('.contenido-slider');
      var current = slider.children('.' + activeClass);
      var currentIndex = +current.index();
      var duration = 250;

      if (direction === 'left') {

        if (currentIndex - 1 < 0) {

          var nextElement = elements.last();

        } else {

          var nextElement = current.prev();

        }

      } else {

        if (currentIndex + 1 >= elements.length) {

          var nextElement = elements.first();

        } else {

          var nextElement = current.next();

        }

      }

      current.css({opacity: 1}).stop(true).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        duration: duration,
        complete: function() {
          current.removeClass(activeClass);

          nextElement.addClass(activeClass);

          nextElement.css({opacity: 0}).stop(true).animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, {
            duration: duration,
            complete: function() {
              slider.removeClass(preventSpamClass)
            }
          })

        }
      })

    }


  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.activo {
  display: block;
}

.contenido-slider {
  background-color: #d0d2ff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: none;
}

.contenido-slider.activo {
  display: block;
}

.contenido-slider span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
}

#arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="slider">
    <div id="1" class="activo contenido-slider">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="contenido-slider">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="contenido-slider">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="4" class="contenido-slider">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div id="5" class="contenido-slider">
      <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-left">Prev</div>
    <div id="arrow-right">next</div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a var and check if the animation is still running:

```
var isAnimating = 0;

$("#arrow-right").click(function(){
    if (!isAnimating) {
      isAnimating = 1;
      nextPrevius(1);
    }
});
```

then in add a callback function in every `fadeIn` event:

```
$("#5").fadeIn("slow", function(){
   isAnimating = 0;
});
```

Comment: Or you can add a custom class to arrow, to identify the clicked button/arrow and remove the class from arrow in fadein event.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#arrow-right").click(function(){
        nextPrevius(1);
    });
    $("#arrow-left").click(function(){
        nextPrevius(-1);
    });
});
```

With the following

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(document).one('click', '#arrow-right',function().   {
        nextPrevius(1);
    });
    $(document).one('click', '#arrow-left', function(){
        nextPrevius(-1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hdie/show the clicked div with the animation, something like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow-right").click(function() {
    nextPrevius(1);
  });
  $("#arrow-left").click(function() {
    nextPrevius(-1);
  });
});

function nextPrevius(value) {
  var buttons = $('#arrow-left,#arrow-right');

  buttons.hide();
  setTimeout(function() {
    buttons.show();
  }, 1000);

  var id = parseInt($(".activo").attr("id"));
  if (id + value < 1) {
    $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $("#5").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
    $("#5").addClass("activo");
  } else if (id + value > 5) {
    $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $("#1").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
    $("#1").addClass("activo");
  } else {
    $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $("#" + (id + value)).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
    $("#" + (id + value)).addClass("activo");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.activo {
  display: block;
}

.contenido-slider {
  background-color: #d0d2ff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.contenido-slider span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
}

#arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="slider">
    <div id="1" class="activo contenido-slider">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="4" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div id="5" class="contenido-slider" style="display:none">
      <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-left">Prev</div>
    <div id="arrow-right">next</div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to work some logic on this code, let me take you step by step,
first of all you need to understand whats happening in here:
once you click you trigger the nextPrevius function which contains a fadeIn function so basically the nextPrevius will only come to an end once the animation is finished, so if you click several times you will trigger several animations one by one, there is a Super Simple solution to this, use a Boolean, let me show you what you need to do:

```
var LagProtector=false;
function nextPrevius(value){
    if(LagProtector==false){
        LagProtector=true;
        var id = parseInt($(".activo").attr("id"));
        if(id+value<1){
            $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#5").fadeIn("slow");
            });
            $(".activo").removeClass("activo");        
            $("#5").addClass("activo");
        }
        else if(id+value>5){
            $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#1").fadeIn("slow");
            });
            $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
            $("#1").addClass("activo");
        }
        else{
            $(".activo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#"+(id+value)).fadeIn("slow");
            });
            $(".activo").removeClass("activo");
            $("#"+(id+value)).addClass("activo");
        }
        LagProtector=false;
    }
}
```

basically what I did is created a Boolean named **LagProtector** and I put all of that code the responsible for animation the slider inside an if that checks if **LagProtector** is triggered already, and if not it set **LagProtector** to true and on the end of the function set it to false. so it will ignore the clicks that were done when the animation was still running. simple and easy.

Comment: Just modified my code using your example and i have the same problem

Comment: well thats because the inner code of that function is written all wrong